# Cómo puedo meter unos datos en una matriz en java

Tags: java

Si tengo en un string por ejemplo `"1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12"` y quiero meter eso en una matriz, ¿cómo hago?. Es decir, yo necesito que en las posiciones de la matriz quede de la siguiente manera.

```
m[0][0] = 1;
m[0][1] = 2;
m[0][2] = 3;
m[0][3] = 4;
m[1][0] = 5;
```

Y así sucesivamente...

```
public class Main { 
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String A = "1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12";
    String matrizA[] = A.split(";");
    String matrizB[] = matrizA[0].split(" "); 
    int tamaño = matrizA.length; 
    String matrizM[][] = new String[tamaño][tamaño];    

    System.out.println(matrizA[0]); 
    System.out.println(matrizB[3]); 
  } 
}
```

La salida del anterior código es esta: `1 2 3 4 4`

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que hayas intentado y qué errores te has encontrado a la hora de desarrollarlo/ejecutarlo

Comment: public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String A = "1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12";
  String matrizA[] = A.split(";");
  String matrizB[] = matrizA[0].split(" ");
  int tamaño = matrizA.length;
  String matrizM[][] = new String[tamaño][tamaño];   
  
  System.out.println(matrizA[0]);
  System.out.println(matrizB[3]);  
 }
}

La salida del anterior código es esta:

1 2 3 4
4

Comment: Pero necesito meter por ejemplo el 1 2 3 y 4 a la fila 0 de la matriz, los siguientes a la fila 2, y los ultimos cuatro a la fila 2 de la matriz, pero no se cómo

Answer (score 1):

La función que necesitas es esta:

```
public int[][] llenarMatrizCon(String datos) {
    String[] filas = datos.trim().split(";");

    int numeroFilas = filas.length;
    int numeroColumnas = filas[0].trim().split(" ").length;

    int[][] resultado = new int[numeroFilas][numeroColumnas];

    for (int i = 0; i < filas.length; i++) {
        String[] elementos = filas[i].trim().split(" ");

        for (int j = 0; j < elementos.length; j++) {
            resultado[i][j] = Integer.valueOf(elementos[j]);
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Y para llamarla es asi:

```
    LlenarMatriz llenarMatriz = new LlenarMatriz();

    String datos = "1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12";

    int[][] resultado = llenarMatriz.llenarMatrizCon(datos);
```

Answer (score 0):

@user7167 Solo voy a realizar algunas modificaciones a tú código. Si la entrada de datos siempre son X números seguido por ";" entonces puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
public class Main { 
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
         String A = "1 2 3 4;5 6 7 8;9 10 11 12"; 
         int x,y; //x -> tamanno matriz A , y -> tamanno matriz B si entre ; hay misma cantidad de numeros
         String matrizA[] = A.split(";"); 
         x = matrizA.length(); // Cantidad de filas de matrizM
         String matrizB[] = matrizA[0].split(" "); // Paso 1
         y = matrizB.length(); // Cantidad de columnas de matrizM
         String matrizM[][] = new String[x][y];
          for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
             if(i>0){
                matrizB[i]=matrizA[i].split(" ");// Como ya teniamos el primer valor de la matrizA[0] en Paso 1, para obtener los otros valores
             }
             for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
                 matrizM[i][j]=matrizB[j];
             } 
          }
```

Si quisieras imprimir la matriz solo tendrias que poner:

```
  for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<y;j++){
        System.out.println(matrizM[i][j]);
     }
  }
```

Cualquier duda o problema escribe.